# Can't save or update products after deleting one Store

Tags: multistore, store-view, magento-1.9.1.1

Under Magento community ver. 1.9.1.1. I have 3 stores and 9 store views (3 store views in each Store). 
After deleting one store, I can no more delete products or update them.

I don't get log files or error messages.

Help.

Comment: what happens when you try to delete something or update?

Comment: @Marius: I get only a red error notice but without an error message in it.